# Encoding in PHP: é chracter is both eÌ and Ã©

Tags: php, youtube

My script takes a webpage, and loads it html (through curl) to a virtual DOMElement. I then gets (among other stuff) the title.

We transform all titles into UTF-8 to save in the database. And it works fine... most of the times. Others, though that's the result:

When I load this url:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aq_2GGwNB9Q
and this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZwIzd-1IHo

you can see both have a "é" in the title. The expectation would be that it would return me the é as "Ã©", but in the second example the é gets echo'ed as "eÌ". Ideas on why that might be happening?

Thanks
Ricardo

Comment: can you show us some code ?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?php       

    $html = file_get_contents("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aq_2GGwNB9Q");
    preg_match_all('/<meta property="og:title" content="(.*?)">/im', $html, $match, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $title = $result[1][0];
    $string = utf8_encode($title);
    echo utf8_decode($string);

?>
```